# Newbie> How can I search and array for a promted word<

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to learn JS and found this "test" but cant figure it out.
I have an array and I need to search through if there are words that start with "syn". I tried few options but nothing worked for me. This I think is the closest Ive got but it still returns empty array. I just needs to be from the start of the word(not in the middle). Can someone please help me?

```js
const data = [
  'Synáček',
  'Alois, synové a bratři',
  'Autosynchro',
  'Sy-noid',
  'Brak a synopie',
  'Brambory',
  'Syntetika'
];

let vyraz = prompt('Výraz', null);

var hledat = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++) {
  if (data.lowerCase[i].includes == vyraz.lowerCase) {
    hledat.push(data[i])
  }
};
console.log(hledat);
```

Comment: You didn't open the DevTools?

Comment: I dont know what that is. I am on repl.it. Ive started to learn few days ago only.

Comment: You have a spelling error (`lenght` instead of `length`), once you fix that, you'll see some errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your code. This is how it should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(vyraz.toLowerCase())){  
  hledat.push(data[i])
  }
};
console.log(hledat);
```

Note that you had a typo in `data.length`. Also the method to transform to lower case is `toLowerCase` instead of `lowerCase` and you forgot the parenthesis after the function calls. `includes` is a method not a property so using it like `someString.includes == something` is not correct. Also in `data.lowerCase[i]` the array index must come after the array like in `data[i].toLowerCase()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now it returns 'Autosynchro', which i dont want because it is inside the word. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @Kevson You can use `startsWith` I updated my answer above

Comment: Ive alredy tried that but for some reason it still gives me the same answers

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.filter()` method with a regex.

```js
const data = [
'Synáček',
'Alois, synové a bratři',
'Autosynchro',
'Sy-noid',
'Brak a synopie',
'Brambory',
'Syntetika'
];

const result = data.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().match(/^syn|\ssyn/));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but 'Alois, synové a bratři' and 'Brak a synopie' should be returned too.